# Ajaxerror when calling WCF Service

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf

I have this WCF method in Test.cs

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string Test()
    {
        return "ok";

    }
```

Test.svc:

```
 <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"   Service="Test" CodeBehind="Test.cs" %>
```

This works OK on my local machine on which I host both the client and WCF in IIS7.
However, when I deploy it to our test server I get this:
I read about cross site scripting restrictions between servers when making WCF call, however, I am on the same domain with client and wcf.

Client: http://mydev.test.com/Test.aspx

Server: http://devwcf.test.com/Test.svc

Ajaxerror 0
undefined

Ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost/Test.svc/Test",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            datatype: "json",
            data: "{}",
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) { alert(result.TestResult) },
            //error: ServiceFailed
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(status);
            }
        });
    });
```

Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings/>
<connectionStrings/>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="EndpBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Test">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Test" behaviorConfiguration="EndpBehavior"/>
  </service>
</services>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You'll get this error when  your WCF and html files on different servers. Use https://github.com/jaubourg/jquery-jsonp . (BTW: If I remember correctly, you have to configure your WCF service to support jsonp, using *crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled* somewhere)

Answer (score 0):

You are not on same domain as subdomains are different for client and service ,browser will still treat as cross domain. You will need to enable CORS for your service , some changes are required in your web.config OR global.asax.cs

In your web.config put below settings

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
</customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

under service model put this , just below serviceHostingEnvironment

```
<standardEndpoints>
<webScriptEndpoint>
<standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
</webScriptEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

If you choose Global.asax.cs , hook up beginrequest event and set headers , in that case no need of above config

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , ”*”);
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS" )
    {

    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods" , "GET, POST" );
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers" , "Content-Type, Accept" );
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age" "1728000" );
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
    }
```

Additionally , you can set these headers in wcf methods also , recommended:

```
if (WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Method == "OPTIONS")

               {
                   WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://Server:Port"); // * doesn't work

           WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");

           WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");

           WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                   return null;
               }
```

To learn more about CORS,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing
Other workarounds are to use JSONP ,wcf JSONP custom behavior :
http://lucbei.wordpress.com/2010/09/06/cross-domain-wcf-rest-with-js-call-3-5-solution

Comment: Thank you, I actually already had global.asax.cs setup exactly as you mentioned. Still no luck.

Comment: Can you see what response you get in Fiddler ? also you can fall back to JSONP alternative.